# Can I dynamically change a Polymer iron-flex-layout (flexbox) based on media query

Tags: polymer, flexbox

I have a Polymer custom element which is a page.  I am using the iron-flex-layout element to provide flexbox classes.  My page's content area contains three paper card elements arranged as follows:-

```
<div class="layout vertical center">
  <div class="layout horizontal wrap">
    <paper-card class="daily layout vertical">...</paper-card>
    <paper-card class="extras layout vertical" >...</paper-card>
  </div>
  <div class="layout horizontal">
    <paper-card class="logout layout vertical">...</paper-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

The width of the paper card elements is exposed to the theme file with a css variable `--pas-menu-card-width` which is currently set to 400px.  I am willing to forego the flexibility of exposing this if there is no other way.

What this gives on a wide screen is two cards (daily and extras) side by side, and the logout card centered below the other two.  On a really wide screen everything is centred and looks good.

As the screen gets narrow such that it is narrower than the first two cards side by side, they just flip so that one is below the other on the left side of the screen.  Unfortunately the third card remains centered in the screen.

What I would like to happen is:-

- either the third card can be left aligned so they all side vertically in a line,
- or, when the first two flip to be one below the other, they get centre aligned on the screen instead of left aligned

Ideally I would like the transition to occur automatically with a media query in my element, but any other mechanism such as some event generated as the top two flip or unflip would be possible.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query?view=demo:demo/index.html) element for that and bind the `query-matches` to a property in your element and to a CSS class or attribute. Some code lines from the iron-media-query element demo:

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{wide}}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query full query="print" query-matches="{{print}}"></iron-media-query>

<div class="item" wide-layout$="{{wide}}">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{print}}">
  </template>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific - I presume I have some css which uses the property wide-layout to do something.  I have been conducting experiements with the browser, and the ideal thing would be to change the classes on the element with the "wrap" class on it to "vertical center"

Comment: The `<iron-media-query>` sets properties to `true`/`false` if a query matches. You can use normal Polymer data-binding to bind these properties to a class (or attribute like `wide-layout` in the example above) and the, as you mentioned, use these classes in your CSS selectors to apply one CSS rule or another.

Comment: Yes I got that, I was wanting to know what rule.  But I figured it out in the end.  I can apply the flexbox mixins with something like  @apply(--layout-horizontal) in the styles selected with [wide-layout] or :not([wide-layout])